# Is there a map of Middle-earth during the second age?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, middle-earth, map

Where can I find a map of Middle-earth during the Second Age circa SA 1600 (before the war of the Elves and Sauron)?

The following site (https://middle-earth.xenite.org/2013/01/09/do-any-maps-accurately-show-beleriand-and-eriador-together/) says:

> The Second Age geography of Middle-earth prior to the Downfall of Númenor was different from the geography depicted by the Third Age map you see published in The Lord of the Rings. So far as I know, Tolkien never made an intermediate map, so we have no idea of what changes rendered by the War of Wrath were modified or wiped out by the Downfall of Númenor.

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/tolkienfans/comments/30zulu/some_more_horrible_maps_of_arda/

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/STOyt - is described as being quite accurate

Comment: Hmm, technically it's not duplicate, but author of this citation is speculating - I see no reason to think there were changes in geography between destruction of Beleriand and Downfall of Numenor

Comment: The sources that I read say that some of the forests were destroyed during the war of Sauron and the Elves and since I was specifically looking for forests, I assume there would be differences.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this as the linked question and its answers are all specifically about *first age* maps.

Answer (score 6):

### J.R.R. Tolkien has only ever drawn a map of Númenor itself, but other notable people have drawn larger scale Second Age maps.

**J.R.R. Tolkien - Map to accompany the manuscript of "Aldarion and Erendis" (later published in *Maker of Middle-earth* and *Voyage en Terre du Milieu*.)**

[image]

<sub>(In *The Great Tales Never End*, Hammond and Scull note that "there are three renderings of Nùmenor among [Tolkien's] papers", however it would seem to be that the other two are unpublished.)</sub>

**Christopher Tolkien - Redrawing of Tolkien's map for print in *Unfinished Tales***

[image]

**Karen Wynn Fonstad - *The Atlas of Middle-earth***

[image]
[image]

**Tom Shippey & John Howe - Amazon's The Lord of the Rings on Prime**

[image]

Comment: He did not really seem to be asking about Numenor.  The question seemed to be about how different continent of Endor might have been.

Comment: @suchiuomizu - I was first just planning to show the Fonstad and Amazon maps, but then thought it would be a shame to skip the one map we *do* have from Tolkien.